# How do I get rid of an InfoPath form on a Sharepoint List?

Tags: list, infopath

I have a SharePoint list that is an InfoPath list and I want to scrap the form. I want to just revert to standard List forms. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just have to go to the List Settings and go to Form Settings and tick the radio button to Use the default SharePoint form and optionally tick the box to delete the InfoPath form.